# During app debugging, I'm getting the following error: "Cannot read property 'answers' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My app was running well, then suddenly it's failed with error "Cannot read property 'answers' of undefined".

Here is the following piece of code:

```
function mapStateToProps({ authedUser, users, questions }) {
    const answeredIds = Object.keys(users[authedUser].answers)
    const answered = Object.values(questions)
        .filter((question) => !answeredIds.includes(question.id))
        .sort((a, b) => b.timestamp - a.timestamp)
    const unanswered = Object.values(questions)
        .filter((question) => answeredIds.includes(question.id))
        .sort((a, b) => b.timestamp - a.timestamp)

    return {
        userQuestionData: {
            answered,
            unanswered,
        }
    }
}
```

...and I can't figure out what is the issue, why and how to solve it?

Any suggestion?

Update:

After doing the suggestion of @Pedro Estrada below, I've introduced `debugger` before the line and has opened the developer tool to inspect and it's appeared the following to me:

[image: Source Tab]

It seems to me that the values of authedUser, users and questions are respectively null, {} and {}; am I right in this analysis? Or are these the values which I should iniciate these variables?

What do you think @Nikhil Goyal and @Pedro Estrada?

Comment: Try checking the values of authedUser and users. That might help in debugging. If the values are coming, can you please update your question with the values?

Comment: Please make sure 'answer' property exists in users and to clarify more provide 'users' and 'authedUser' mock data.

Comment: @Nikhil Goyal, how could I check their values?

Comment: @jose-renato-m use console.log statements at the beginning of the method.

Comment: @Nikhil Goyal, sorry to bother you. I'm kind a little new on coding, I know the command console.log, but I'm not figuring out where and how could I put it on my code. Could you point exactly where I could use it?

Comment: Just at the beginning of the function mapStateToProps so in case even if error also comes, it will first output the values for those variables and then will throw the error. That way, we can check what is the issue.

Comment: @Nikhil Goyal, please see the update above.

Comment: See your ```authedUser``` is coming as ```null``` which will result in ```users[authedUser]``` as ```undefined``` as ```users``` won't be having a key named ```null```. As the first argument to this method will be state object. Can you please send your reducer code so that we can determine what state is there and based on that, try to find the solution of the issue you are facing.

Comment: @Nikhil Goyal, sorry to take long time to answer your words. In this middle time I've debugged the code, but it's appeared too much issues. I've need to open a new branch in Git and I've started a code a little bit more simple and I was focused on it and I haven't opened Stackoverflow until today, sorry. But I appreciate for your contribution and for the other guys' contribution too, thank you so much. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is on this line:

```
const answeredIds = Object.keys(users[authedUser].answers)
```

It means that `users[authedUser]` is returning `undefined` and you're trying to get the value of the property `answers` of undefined.

I would put a breakpoint on that line and seeing why its `undefined`

---

To add a breakpoint you can do this 2 ways:
First open the chrome debugger by hitting <kbd>F12</kbd> or right clicking on your page and clicking `Inspect` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (on windows)

1. Add the keyword `debugger;` right above the line that's failing and run through the code
2. In the chrome debugger, go to the `Source` tab and find your javascript and click on the numbers on the left to add a breakpoint

Comment: @jose-renato-m i amended my answer to include how to add a breakpoint